# Drag and move image using plain JavaScript doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've gone ahead and implemented a drag feature for my image that should move the image in whichever direction you drag the image. I;m not sure whats wrong with it, if its slow and needs to be throttled, if my maths off, or I'm just plain doing something wrong. I made a minimal viable example. Any help would be really appreciated.

[Here's a codepen.](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/eZvBMz)

### HTML

```
<div class="img-cntnr">
  <img class="my-img" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/900/900" alt="" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.img-cntnr {
  position: relative;
  border: dodgerBlue solid 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-cntnr img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
```

### JS

```
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName('my-img');
  var imgCntnrs = document.getElementsByClassName('img-cntnr');
  var dragImgMouseStart = {};
  var imgCntnrH;
  var imgCntnrW;

  function mousedownDragImg(e) {
    dragImgMouseStart.x = e.pageX;
    dragImgMouseStart.y = e.pageY;
    imgCntnrH = imgCntnrs[0].offsetHeight;
    imgCntnrW = imgCntnrs[0].offsetWidth;

    // add listeners for mousemove, mouseup
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveDragImg);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupDragImg);
  }

  function mousemoveDragImg(e) {
    var diffX = -1 * (dragImgMouseStart.x - e.pageX);
    var diffY = -1 * (dragImgMouseStart.y - e.pageY);
    var oldLeft = isNaN(parseFloat(images[0].style.left)) ? 0 : parseFloat(images[0].style.left);
    var newLeft = oldLeft + diffX / imgCntnrW;
    images[0].style.left = newLeft + '%';
    var oldTop = isNaN(parseFloat(images[0].style.top)) ? 0 : parseFloat(images[0].style.top);
    var newTop = oldTop + diffY / imgCntnrH;
    images[0].style.top = newTop + '%';
    console.log(newLeft, newTop);
  }

  function mouseupDragImg(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveDragImg);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseupDragImg);
  }

  for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // make images unselectable
    images[i].ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
  };

  images[0].addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownDragImg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few rectifications needed in your code.

- First of all all DOM access must be done through `requestAnimationFrame()`. Then i had to refactor the code for a better performance. Moving DOM objects are best done by CSS3 `transform: translate(x,y);`
- Then I had to refactor the code further. I modified the semantics a little bit. In order to move the image element we will "only" alter the `transform: translate(x,y);` CSS property as we move the mouse. So we only need this CSS property's initial values. Since you have chosen to center the over-sized image horizontally by doing `left: 50%;` (first move the image to the right up until it's left edge is at the containing div's half width) then `transform: translateX(-50%);` (move the image to the left as much as haft of it's width) we can easily see that our `translateX` value is half of the image width (-50%). The `translateY` value has never been modified so it remains as 0. I have changed this property into `transform: translate(-50%, 0);` for consistency. Well, now lets calculate our initial `x` value for the `translate(x,y)`. The `image.getBoundingClientRect()` tool is very useful to get the width of the `image` element in integers.

So please see the below snippets for the rest. It's pretty self explanatory.

Also at JSBin and CodePen

https://jsbin.com/bawalebowi/1/edit?css,js,output

http://codepen.io/omerillo/pen/EKWOZQ

```js
  var         image = document.getElementsByClassName('my-img')[0],
          imgCntnrs = document.getElementsByClassName('img-cntnr'),
  dragImgMouseStart = {},
           lastDiff = {x:0, y:0},
         initialPos = image.getBoundingClientRect(),
         currentPos = {x: -initialPos.width/2, y: 0};

  function mousedownDragImg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dragImgMouseStart.x = e.clientX;
    dragImgMouseStart.y = e.clientY;
          currentPos.x += lastDiff.x;
          currentPos.y += lastDiff.y;
               lastDiff = {x: 0, y: 0};
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveDragImg);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupDragImg);
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                            image.style.transform = "translate(" + (currentPos.x + lastDiff.x) + "px," + (currentPos.y + lastDiff.y) + "px)";
                          });
  }

  function mousemoveDragImg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    lastDiff.x = e.clientX - dragImgMouseStart.x;
    lastDiff.y = e.clientY - dragImgMouseStart.y;
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                            image.style.transform = "translate(" + (currentPos.x + lastDiff.x) + "px," + (currentPos.y + lastDiff.y) + "px)";
                          });
  }

  function mouseupDragImg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveDragImg);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseupDragImg);
  }

  image.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownDragImg);
```

```css
.img-cntnr {
  position: relative;
  border: dodgerBlue solid 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.img-cntnr img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 0px;
  bottom:0px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img-cntnr">
  <img class="my-img" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/900/900" alt="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An exemplar of well written answers.